# How to get usercontrol HorizontalScroll or VerticalScroll value in .Net 1.1

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, user-controls, .net-1.1

I am using .Net Framework 1.1 for developing the usercontrol.  whenever the data exceeding above `AutoScrollMinSize` then scrollbar has appeared. In .Net 1.1 I can't find any event for scroll and can't get scroll value also.

In .Net 2.0 or above , we have `HorizontalScroll` or `VerticalScroll` properties . Based on these properties we can get the scroll value. But , In .Net 1.1  can't find any properties or methods to get the scroll value.

Comment: What is the container control you're using in .NET 1.1? You're saying that you expect it to have an AutoScrollMinSize property but you can't see that property??

Comment: I inherit usercontrol to my custom control and set AutoScrollMinSize on specific size . whenever control resize if control goes to less than the AutoscrollMinSize then scroll has appeared . if i move scrollbar , then i need scroll value and scroll change event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to work with the AutoScrollPosition property (bit.ly/2qZrtpN). To detect changes to the auto-generated scrollbar, the only way to do that in 1.1 is to create an event handler for the Paint event. This documentation (bit.ly/2vNPmWt) is for 2.0 but should apply also to 1.1.